# Creating a group for a repeating table in Infopath 2013

Tags: 2013, infopath, groups

So, I am trying to recreate something that another developer built and running into some difficulties. I would like to create a repeating table in InfoPath to display my historical comments, like this:
[image: Screenshot]

I have looked at what they did in InfoPath and know how to make a repeating table. The part I'm having trouble with is getting InfoPath 2013 to let me create a group that is not a people picker. 
I'm sure that I am just missing something basic and would really appreciate some direction. Microsoft support is, as usual, not very helpful.

Comment: Someone in my office mentioned appending but I cannot seem to find that option anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a field like the one pictured above, you would need to go into the list settings, advanced, and turn on appending. Then you would go into InfoPath, remove the fields from your form and add them back. This is actually a really simple process that I spent a solid 72 hours trying to figure out.